Permission error on server for storage cache folder in laravel 8
I am getting this error from time to time on the AWS Linux server after clearing the cache as well.
Cache is stored via command and from the website as well when we try to send notifications.
Exception: Unable to create lockable file: /var/www/slimmed-portal/slimmed-laravel-portal/slimmed-webapp/storage/framework/cache/data/7c/03/7c03173b86fb6f8da70a851cb194864a4eec0df4. Please ensure you have permission to create files in this location.

I tried below things to resolve the error
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/framework/cache/data
chown -R apache storage/framework/cache/data

sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache
chown -R apache bootstrap/cache

And after clearing the cache it still comes back in like 1 or 2 days later:
php artisan optimize:clear

Can anyone provide a proper solution to this error? It would be very helpful.

are the permissions changing between your chmod/chown and the time the error shows up again?

no permission change is still the same

if when changing the permissions it works, and somehow fails later. more info is needed on the failing process. Does it fail from a queue job or scheduled command? Does it work from http?

I am not able to check exactly when it was failing but when we call the API suddenly an error will come front side i have react and in laravel, we have only API
